# Can we safely uninstall the *.dbg packages

Tags: package-management, debugging

I use ***Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS***.

I've found some ****.dbg*** packages installed into my system. I can see them when I use ***Synaptic Package Manage***r.

I wonder if those packages are absolutely necessary and if we could safely uninstalled them.

Some idea?

Comment: Try removing the packages using apt's `--simulate` flag, and see what happens.

Comment: @user535733 I tried it before and I got... nothing bad and/or visible unsusual! So...

Comment: Then you have your answer: Yes, you can safely uninstall those packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug packages are not absolutely necessary. It helps when generating a bug report to the Ubuntu programmers who can then determine what happen with more ease (otherwise, they have to match IP addresses *manually* when looking at your bug report).

So if you want to help making Ubuntu better with bug reports that are easier to work on, it's nice to have the debug packages installed. Also, if you're a programmer, it can be useful to you while... debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation!!!